# Sci-fi book about a family of aliens with blue hair, who go to a dystopian dimension where the sick or the old are killed

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Okay so there's this book I read, probably back in 4th or 5th grade. Definitely dystopian sci-fi.

It was about this family of aliens with like special blue hair, and they went to this dystopian dimension. In the dimension I remember the sick or the old were killed and they all wore the same clothes, **I think.** The ending of the book was about the family trying to stop their grandmother from dying due to the old age thing and then escaping the city.

If you can help me find it, thank you; I wanna reread some old books I used to like. <3

Answer (score 6):

[You'll Like It Here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9460533-you-ll-like-it-here) (Everybody Does) by Ruth White.

[image: You'll Like It Here]

> While Meggie and David Blue are from another planet, they're a lot like Earth kids, with similar hopes and dreams, and can't wait to grow up. BUT they also have GROSSLY UNIQUE qualities, such as blue streaks in their hair that pop up randomly and language skills that sound like nothing on this planet. The story takes these alien kids, along with their mother and grandfather, by accident, to a far planet in which the society is not only oppressive but hostile to individual freedom. People are kept submissive through drugs and brainwashing. The Blues, who have spent time in free societies recognize the upside-down-ness of this world. They're almost helpless to do anything, but do what they can, plan their escape, and vow to help others.